# Unable to know how to link data between two tables

Tags: rest, jdbc

I'm learning RESTful webservices from javabrains website. Here there is a section named `Comments` and this is related to a message, But I'm unable to know How Can I link these both.

Below is my SQL Tables for Messages and comments.

**Messages**

[image]

**Comments**

[image]

Here Basically, both look pretty same(The table design), but the values differ. And I'm using the below method to send the data.

```
public Comment addComment(long messageId, Comment comment) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
    String userName = properties.getProperty("user");
    String password = properties.getProperty("pass");
    String url = properties.getProperty("Sqldburl");
    int key = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        String query = "select count(*) from Comments";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        key = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        String query = "insert into Comments(id, message, author) values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, key);
        ps.setString(2, comment.getMessage());
        ps.setString(3, comment.getAuthor());
        ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        String query = "select * from Comments where messageId=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setLong(1, messageId);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            comment.setAuthor(rs.getString("Author"));
            comment.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
            comment.setMessage(rs.getString("message"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e + "b3");
    }
    return comment;
}
```

After writing this code, I've realized that Here I'm adding a comment for sure into `Comments` table, But it is no where linked to the `Messages`.

I know a way, that is I've create a new column in the Comments table and using `join` operation, I need to update the same `messageId` in comments table. But I want to know if there is a better way of getting this done, without using the concept of joins.

In `MessageBean`, there is a map declared as below.

```
private Map<Long, Comment> comments = new HashMap<>();
@XmlTransient
public Map<Long, Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(Map<Long, Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
```

can I take any advantage of this to avoid `join`?